# If $(x_n)$ is a sequence such that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{{x^4_k}}n\to 0$, then $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{{x_k}}n\to 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a sequence such that

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{{x^4_k}}n=0.$
How do I show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{{x_k}}n=0$?

Comment: If I remember well, this is duplicate. The answer given was that a first application of CS inequality gives $(\frac{\sum|x_k|}{n})^2\leq \frac{\sum x_k^2}{n}$, and a second application do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the [Cauchy-Schwarz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) inequality, $(u\cdot v)^2 \leq ||u||^2 ||v||^2$, on the vectors $u=(1,1,\ldots,1)$ and $v=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ we get

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)^2 \leq \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2\sum_{k=1}^n 1 = n \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2$$

Now applying the same inequality, but on the vectors $u=(1,1,\ldots,1)$ and $v=(x_1^2,x_2^2,\ldots,x_n^2)$ we get

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2\right)^2 \leq \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^4\sum_{k=1}^n 1 = n\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^4$$

Putting the two inequalities above togeather we find

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)^4 \leq n^2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2\right)^2 \leq n^3\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^4$$

or

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k}{n}\right| \leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k^4}{n}\right)^{1/4}$$

Since the right hand side vanishes in the limit $n\to \infty$ so does the left hand side.

Comment: First to upvote! :-)